# Does a half-crossover design exist?

Tags: experiment-design, crossover-study

I've read about incomplete crossover designs, where subjects do not complete all treatments. However, I haven't seen anything about subjects completing all treatments, but not all treatment combinations exist. Is this possible?

In a replicated crossover (eg 2 treatments, 4 periods), not all 16 combinations are always used. At least in the papers/examples I've read, usually it's 2 or 4 sequences (ABAB/BABA, ABAB/BABA/ABBA/BBAA).

What I mean by a half-crossover is an experiment with:

- 3 treatments, 3 periods, but 2 sequences (ABC/BAC)
- 4 treatments, 4 periods, 2 or 3 sequences (ABCD/DBAC)

Can this be an experimental design?

I am guessing a disadvantage of using something like this is that the carryover effect cannot be estimated, since not all combinations exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inability to estimate carryover effects may not matter: Stephen Senn, for example, has argued that the way to approach carryover effects is to have washout periods rather than to try to make strong enough assumptions that they can be estimated.

A problem with ABC/BAC is that C is always last and so is completely confounded with any effect of being in period 3 (confounded with time and order).

Your four-period, two-sequence design doesn't have quite as bad order/period issues (though B is always in period 2). Even so, the question would be whether there's an advantage to restricting the number of sequences. If you have, say, 20 participants, do you do better in some way with 10 in each of two sequences than with 5 in each of four sequences?

(One setting where there definitely are fewer sequences than treatments is the n-of-1 study, where there are at least two treatments and only one sequence (per individual))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have given me a lot to think about and read further. 

So, provided the washout periods were long enough and the same treatment wasn't offered in the same period, using a four-treatment, four-period, two-sequence would still be statistically correct/valid/acceptable? 

I see it is not necessarily ideal, but I could imagine lack of resources or something could be a reason for conducting a study like this.